# Add keyboard shortcuts to comments

Tags: script, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

### Question code is obsolete.

But the answer code and the code linked in the comments still work.

---

### About

This script adds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (bold), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (italic), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (code), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (link) shortcuts to comments.

My script doesn't work *exactly* the same as the question/answer text editors, but it's similar.  One difference is that hitting Ctrl+B when no text is selected just puts `**` in the window, as opposed to putting `**strong text**` with "strong text" selected.  This means you can use the shortcuts like you would in a word processor: hit Ctrl+B to enter bold mode, type what you want, then hit Ctrl+B again to back out.  (Actually the question/answer text editors behave similar to this, but uses trickier javascript to accomplish it.)

For links, I'm using simple JS `prompt()` function, rather than trying to hook into the text box that is built-in for adding links questions/answers.

#### <del>Download</del>

[view obsolete source](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/62158.html) (the script doesn't currently work; see the comments and answer, below.)

#### Change History

- 2012-03-26: Added support for Ctrl+L
- 2009-07-18: Initially released

#### Platform

Tested on Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 9.0, on Windows 7. Requires Greasemonkey on Firefox.

#### License

Do whatever you want, as long as you don't sell it or claim you wrote it yourself. If you make any cool modifications, let me know!

#### Obsolete Source

Beware that **this script needs to be modified per the answer, below**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          stackoverflow comments formatting shortcuts
// @namespace     stackoverflow
// @description   Adds Ctrl+B (bold), Ctrl+I (italic), Ctrl+K (code), and Ctrl+L (link) keyboard shortcuts to comments.
// @include       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include       http://superuser.com/*
// @include       http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include       http://serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include       http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include       http://nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com/*
// @include       http://seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://meta.seasonedadvice.com/*
// @include       http://crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://askdifferent.com/*
// @include       http://meta.crossvalidated.com/*
// @include       http://stackapps.com/*
// @include       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @author        Kip Robinson - http://stackoverflow.com/users/18511/kip
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
  function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }; 

  with_jquery(function($) {
    $('textarea[name=comment]').live('keydown', function(e) {
      //Ctrl+[BIKL]
      if(e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && (e.which == 66 || e.which == 73 || e.which == 75 || e.which == 76))
      {
        //all text
        var text = $(this).val();

        //text before selection
        var before = text.substring(0,this.selectionStart);

        //selectect text
        var selected = text.substring(this.selectionStart,this.selectionEnd);

        //text after selection
        var after = text.substring(this.selectionEnd,text.length);

        //length of selection
        var selLen = selected.length;

        //markup character that will go before/after section. (Note: link is handled a bit differently.)
        var markup = '';
        var isLink = false;
        if(e.which == 66)
          markup = '**';
        else if(e.which == 73)
          markup = '*';
        else if(e.which == 75)
          markup = '`';
        else
          isLink = true;

        //markup length
        var mLen = markup.length;

        //replace is what the selected text will be replaced with
        var replace = '';
        if(selLen == 0)
        {
          //nothing selected. just print the markup
          if(isLink)
          {
            var url = prompt('Please input link URL');
            var linkText = prompt('Please input link text');
            replace = '[' + linkText + '](' + url + ')';
          }
          else
          {
            replace = markup;
          }
        }
        else if(!isLink && selLen > 2*mLen
                && selected.substring(0,mLen) == markup
                && selected.substring(selLen - mLen, selLen) == markup)
        {
          //We have selected something that starts and ends with the markup. We will remove the markup in
          //this case. For example, "*sometext*" becomes just "sometext". This is not available for links.
          replace = selected.substring(mLen, selLen - mLen);
        }
        else
        {
          //we have selected something. put the markup before and after it.
          if(isLink)
          {
            var url = prompt('Please input link URL');
            replace = '[' + selected + '](' + url + ')';
          }
          else
          {
            replace = markup + selected + markup;
          }
        }

        //now update the text
        $(this).val(before + replace + after);

        if(selLen > 0)
        {
          //if something was selected, make the result selected too.
          this.selectionStart = before.length;
          this.selectionEnd = before.length + replace.length;
        }
        else
        {
          //nothign was selected, so put the cursor at the end of the updated text.
          this.selectionEnd = this.selectionStart = before.length + replace.length;
        }

        e.stopPropagation(); //prevent bubbling (new-school)
        return false; //prevent bubbling (old-school)
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: **Bug Report:** Press `Ctrl L` when editing a comment. Input a URL and press `Enter` (instead of clicking *OK* in the input dialog). Comment gets submitted immediately (after linking the selected text).

Comment: Also, in Firefox, pressing *Ctrl-L* shows the JS input dialog but the cursor is in the address bar. I have to click in the JS input box before pasting the URL. In Chrome, the JS dialog (which looks a lot nicer) already had focus so I could paste immediately. I guess this is a browser issue you can't fix on the add-on, but if you can, that will be great.

Comment: I can't get this to work right now on Chrome for OS X.

Comment: I have published a more refined and improved userscript that does the same and much more: [Comment keyboard shortcuts](//stackapps.com/q/7923)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excellent script, much needed. I adjusted the following to make it work:

- changed `live` by `$(document).on( 'keydown', 'textarea[name=comment]', function(e) {})`
- added `metakey` so it works on Macs `(e.ctrlKey||e.metaKey)`

And other improvements:

- only runs when [viewing a question](https://stackapps.com/a/4904/10590) or in the Review/Task pages.
- changed `@include` by `@match` [using a format](https://stackapps.com/a/4892/10590) that catches both main and meta sites `*://*.stackapps.com/questions*`

Here's the [modified script](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/a539c1905608b253fcb6#file-commentsformattingshortcuts-user-js).

Comment: thanks i had noticed this stopped working but never got around to investigating why. jquery deprecation of `.live()` makes sense!

Comment: Please, feel free to incorporate whatever you want into the question's code. Also, pointing to a raw Gist/Github URL works ok. Cheers!

Comment: The script in OP didn't work for me. But this correction has no "install" link. How do I install it?

Comment: @Revetahw: Press "raw" button on the page to access code and your userscript manager should start installation.