# Stack Exchange userscript template / boilerplate

Tags: support, javascript, scripts

I find it annoying to have to type the entire list of Stack Exchange sites to include every single time I make a new userscript. Furthermore, jQuery isn't automatically included by default.

Is there a template I can use in order be able to start writing code (including jQuery), drag it into my browser, and have it Just Work™?

Comment: Related: [Complete list of sites to include / match into my script?](http://stackapps.com/q/4188/7653)

Answer (score 9):

`template.user.js`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Stack Exchange Userscript (Template)
// @grant none
// @match *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// ==/UserScript==

var userscript = function($) {

// INSERT YOUR USERSCRIPT CODE HERE

};

var el = document.createElement('script');
el.type = 'text/javascript';
el.text = '(' + userscript + ')(jQuery);';
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

This template will

1. Guarantee that your script can only run on Stack Exchange sites
2. Run on all Stack Exchange sites (as of 7-10-2014, will be updated as necessary if new sites with unique URLs are added)
3. Allow you to reliably use `$` as `jQuery` within your userscript
4. Be compatible with all major browsers (really not that fancy; should work virtually anywhere)

Comment: This misses some sites and most of the meta sites.  Use `//*.` for all lines.

Comment: You should also add a `@name` line since its omission will cause sneaky problems.  Likewise `@grant none` is a good idea as a start/baseline.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks, forgot about that. Edited. (*.stackoverflow.com doesn't match stackoverflow.com, though.)

Comment: Yes it does. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns .

Comment: @BrockAdams Hmm, I was not aware of that. Editing again

Comment: PS: recommend `changeThis` for the `@name` as it's a hint and easy to set with one double-click.

Comment: Not bad. I still like using the page's jQ as shown in [this post](https://stackapps.com/revisions/3341/7) as it avoids some timing issues and makes debugging a bit easier.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one for css too:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          changeMe
// @namespace     http://use.your.homepage/
// @version       0.1
// @description   addSomethingUseful
// @match http*://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match http*://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match http*://*.superuser.com/*
// @match http*://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match http*://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match http*://*.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match http*://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match http*://stackapps.com/*
// @copyright  2014+, You
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==


function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle (function(){/*
    //Add your code below.  

*/}.toString()
   .slice(14,-3))
```

Comment: `.slice(14,-3)` is a master stroke, nice technique!

Comment: @brasofilo yeah, but I got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15558082/4071709

Answer (score 3):

I'm detecting which page we are using the StackExchange object:

[image: object contents]

The property `StackExchange.options.routeName` can be (among other values):

- Questions/Show (`/questions/POST-ID`)
- Questions/List (`/questions`)
- Questions/ListByTag (`/questions/tagged/TAG-NAME`)

So, to run a script only when viewing an individual post:

```
var userscript = function($) {

    if( ( StackExchange.options.routeName.indexOf('Questions/Show') === -1 ) ) 
        return;

    // INSERT YOUR USERSCRIPT CODE HERE
};
```

<sub>**PS:** I don't know why, but Chrome detects the object at the root of the userscript, but Firefox only inside our `userscript` function. Inside our function works on both browsers.</sub>