# Comment keyboard shortcuts

Tags: script, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

#### About

This userscript adds keyboard shortcuts to StackExchange comments. The default ones are: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (bold), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (italic), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (code), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (link). You can yourself extend this with more custom <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>single_key</kbd> shortcuts as required (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> 
 can give `UNICORNselectionUNICORN` ;) ). This works in all SE site comments, as well as the chatbox on all chat.SE and chat.SO.

This extension works the same way as the actual StackExchange editor works:
such that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> with nothing selected inserts a placeholder (`**strong text**`), while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> with existing bold text un-boldens it. Trailing whitespaces are also handled similarly.

For links, this uses the `prompt()` dialog box. It automatically prepends `http://` as a default, otherwise the inline Markdown links don't work.

The only difference from the SE editor is that this userscript uses the single underscore (`_`) instead of the single asterisk (`*`) for italics as a default. This is mainly to prevent clashes between bold and italics form (and their wrapping and unwrapping) when they are nested.

#### Download

GitHub - [**Install link**](https://gist.github.com/GaurangTandon/860cbdef7355fa2978dc4bd3cb408981/raw/c6075a44bba8d87bc4e602a684fad5fb61a34667/Comment%2520keyboard%2520shortcuts.user.js) and [View source](https://gist.github.com/GaurangTandon/860cbdef7355fa2978dc4bd3cb408981)

#### Platform

Tested on Chrome 66 (Tampermonkey) and Firefox 60 (Greasemonkey) on Windows 10

#### Notes:

1. **How to extend this with custom shortcuts?**

   - open the source with your local monkey and head over to around line 35 at the declaration `var WRAPPERS =`
   - each wrapper uses the format: `keycode: ["placeholder", "delimiter"]` which I think is fairly straightforward
   - so, for the above example, just do `85: ["unicornify!", "UNICORN"]`. Also, don't forget the comma to separate this from the previous wrapper!
   - you can get the keycode for your key via http://keycode.info
2. This userscript differs from the [previous one](https://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments) as:

   - it didn't allow custom wrappers
   - it didn't work the same way the SE editor does (specifically, you needed to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> twice, also it had no support for un-boldening)
3. This userscript is currently a beta release, and will be updated as a formal release after a week's testing.

#### License

Do whatever you wish to do, just don't sell this for money (but may use it in a commercial software's code) or state that you made it yourself. Do post here an answer if you do something cool with this :D

#### Contribute

Post bugs or feature requests as answers below!